# How to choose Multiple Redis Connection based on configuration in Lettuce - Standalone, RedisCluster and Sentinel.?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, lettuce

I have a requirement of supporting the multiple redis connections.

The requirement is Why Can't we have a Generic Connection Object like Connection instead of having the StatefulRedisConnection and StatefulRedisClusterConnection ?

Why we have RedisClient and RedisClusterClient instead of generic Client object that can connect to any of the types of connection like Standalone, Sentinel and Cluster?

**How to achieve the factory pattern by switching the Standalone, cluster or sentinel when I say connectionType=cluster (or) connectionType=sentinel in commandline args?**

```
 RedisClient client = RedisClient.create(redisURI);
        AbstractRedisClient abstractRedisClient = RedisClient.create(redisURI);
        abstractRedisClient = RedisClusterClient.create(redisURI);
        AbstractRedisClient finalAbstractRedisClient = abstractRedisClient;

        GenericObjectPool<StatefulRedisConnection<String, String>> pool = ConnectionPoolSupport
                .createGenericObjectPool(() -> (finalAbstractRedisClient instanceof RedisClient) ? ((RedisClient) finalAbstractRedisClient).connect() : ((RedisClusterClient) finalAbstractRedisClient).connect(), new GenericObjectPoolConfig());
        try (StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = pool.borrowObject()) {
            RedisCommands<String, String> commands = connection.sync();
            pong = commands.ping();
        }
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for your question?